# Converting Windows help file to a more user friendly format?

Tags: windows, conversion

Is there any free (as in bird) tool to convert windows help files (*.hlp) to a more user friendly format such as html/rtf?

Answer (score 5):

Some searching revealed this free tool, [HelpDeco](http://www.geocities.com/mwinterhoff/helpdeco.htm).  I tried it out and it seems to be able to create an RTF file from a standard HLP file (using the "/r" option).  It generates images as well, but it seemed to create BMP files which wouldn't display in Word 2007 or Wordpad.  (I assume converting them to WMF or PNG files might make them display properly.)

Comment: GeoCities has been discontinued, but HelpDeco also has a sourceforge project at https://sourceforge.net/projects/helpdeco/, so it's still possible to get it.

Comment: The original GeoCities page is archived on Oocities here: https://www.oocities.org/mwinterhoff/helpdeco.htm (the HELPDECO.ZIP file linked from the page - which contains the decompiler itself - is archived as well). I just used HelpDeco to decompile a HLP file from 1997 on Windows 10 with no issues. It created an RTF file, a few other files, and several indexed-color BMP files. I was able to open the BMP files with both the Windows image viewer and GIMP.

Comment: This is the first reference (the sourceforge location of helpdeco and the files included in that zip) I have found to actual documentation of the Microsoft WinHelp old help file format (see the helpfile.txt in helpdeco-2.1.4.tar.gz). Dunno if will compile it or not, having used https://github.com/knuth-konrad/winhlp32-on-windows10 instructions to restore use of WinHlp32.exe on Windows 8 (like herding cats working on Windows, but finally succeeded).

Answer (score 2):

[**ABC Amber HLP Converter**](http://www.processtext.com/abchlp.html) allows you to create printable, manual-quality documents from Microsoft Windows Help files. The program converts hlp files to any document (and database) format you wish - **PDF, RTF, HTML, DOC, CHM, TXT, DBF, XML, CSV, XLS, MDB,** etc.

EDIT: I found a free solution, but this will convert HLP to RTF only, it might suit your needs. It's a command line decompiler but some gentle soul has written a GUI for it. Here goes:

Download [Help Decompiler 2.1](http://www.help-info.de/download/WinHelp_decompiler.zip) and [HlpDecoGUI](http://www.help-info.de/download/WinHelp_decompiler_GUI-1.zip) and extract both archives to the same folder.

For the first time you launch **HlpDecoGUI** you'll have to point to the decompiler (**HELPDECO.EXE**), then pick the HLP file you wish to decompile, select the output directory and hit start.

[image]

This is an optional part of a nice tutorial about [**Converting WinHelp (HLP) to HTMLHelp (CHM)**](http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_WinHelp/hw_converting.htm)

Comment: It isn't free, just the demo version is free

Comment: Using HlpDecoGUI worked for me. The links in this solution do not work anymore, but I was able to download those tools [here](https://www.oocities.org/dipakauddy/hlpdecogui.htm).

Answer (score 1):

there' s a tutorial about that in this web page: http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_WinHelp/hw_converting.htm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I found this: http://www.herdsoft.com/ftp/downloads.html

Comment: Hmm, well, that looks like a trial version mostly ...